# iOS developer certificate private key lost

Tags: ios, code-signing-certificate

I got stuck in this problem for like 2 days now. I have updated my OS and Xcode so I have to download my developer certificate. When I accessed it in the keychain access it doesn't have its private key. And Xcode throws an exception that private key is missing. I have done revoking and requesting the certificate but it still does not solve the problem. What solution can possibly solve my problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you remove the old certificate from the keychain before requesting a new certificate? Did you request the certificate via Xcode?

Comment: yup. I have remove all. I have requested via xcode

Comment: try in your Xcode **Preferences** - **Accounts** - **View Details...** - **Download All**.

Answer (score 0):

Private key is needed, it is fundamental. Try to find it. If it is really gone, Use a new private key to apply a new certificate.